# Prove this binomial coefficient equation

Tags: analysis, discrete-mathematics, binomial-coefficients, binomial-distribution

I'm supposed to prove the following:
$$ \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} \binom{2n-2-i}{i} =  \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} \binom{n-1+i}{i}$$

Is there any simple conversion to come from the first term to the second one?

Comment: However, the left side is equal to $$\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\binom{n-1+i}{2i}.$$

Comment: Specifically, taking $j=n-1-i,$ you get the left side is:$$\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}\binom{n-1+j}{n-1-j}=\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}\binom{n-1+j}{2j}$$

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is not true. Say $n=2$, we get:

$$ \sum_{i=0}^1 \binom{2-i}{i} =  {2\choose 0}+ {1\choose 1} = 1+1=2$$

but
$$\sum_{i=0}^1 \binom{1+i}{i}=  {1\choose 0}+  {2\choose 1}= 1+2=3  $$

Comment: (+1) You saved me some time...

Comment: Shame on me!! You're right